# How can i get know that my String contains diacritics?

Tags: java, character-encoding

For Example -

```
text = Československá obchodní banka;

text string contains diacritics like Č , á etc.
```

I want to write a function where i will pass this string "Československá obchodní banka" and  `function will return true if string contains diacritics else false`.

I have to handle diacritics and string which contains character which doesn't fall in A-z or a-z range separately.

```
1) If String contains diacritics then I have to do some XXXXXX on it.

2) If String contains character other than A-Z or a-z and not contains diacritics  then do some other operations YYYYY.
```

I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: What's the use case? By "diacritics" do you really mean that you want to look for letters that contain diacritics, or do you mean *any letter* that is not in the range A-Z? What about non-latin letters like 'じ' which you may argue contain the Japanese equivalent of diacritics?

Comment: why not check each character in the string and parse it to an int, anything over 127 would be a diacritic

Comment: @David That's a little too simplistic and exactly why I was asking what I was asking above. I wasn't aware that "µ" contains diacritics.

Comment: @deceze Lol, yes true, completely left me at the time of writing :)

Comment: I have to handle diacritics and string which contains character which doesn't fall in  A-z or a-z range separately.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One piece of knowledge: in Unicode there exists a code for `á` but the same result one may get with an `a` and a `combining mark-'`.

You can use [java.text.Normalizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html), as follows:

```
public static boolean hasDiacritics(String s) {
    // Decompose any á into a and combining-'.
    String s2 = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    return s2.matches("(?s).*\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}.*");
    //return !s2.equals(s);
}
```

Comment: I corrected my answer: if the original s already contained a decomposed a` an equals test would not succeed.

Answer (score 5):

The [Normalizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) class seems to be able to accomplish this. Some limited testing indicate that

```
Normalizer.isNormalized(text, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
```

might be what you need.